# Asp.Net Wep Api - Return Internal Server Error with exception details

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way I can return internal server error with the exception details?

For example if I have something like the following:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult test(MyDto dto)
 {
      using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
      {
            try
            {
                //do some stuff

                transaction.Commit();
                return Ok();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();

                return InternalServerError(new Exception(ex.Message));
            }
       }
 }
```

Which give me the following. but as you can see there is no inner exception details to provide any meaningful information.

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the 
                       inner exception for details.",
   "exceptionType": "System.Exception",
  "stackTrace": null
}
```

Basically I would like some more info regarding the exception as an when it occurs so that I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to expose the exception details is to set the configuration property IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = Always in your HttpConfiguration or. Web.conf.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api

After that, you can throw your execption and asp.net creates the InternalServerError-Response.

Another way is to create your own error object and retuns it with the information.

But you should be careful with providing to much information about your internal server information for security reasones.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{  
  Logger.Info("WebApiConfig: Register: Start");
  config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
  // ...
}



 [HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult test(MyDto dto)
 {
      using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
      {
            try
            {
                //do some stuff

                transaction.Commit();
                return Ok();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
       }
 }
```

Comment: @P-Grote I'm trying the following `return InternalServerError(new Exception(ex.Message))` but it doesn't seem to include the inner exception details?

Comment: Yes, that's because you creating a new exception object and includes only the original message. Extend your catch block like this `catch (Exception ex)` and pass the exception.

Comment: @P-Grote using your method by simply calling `throw` seems to work without any further configuration as shown in your answer. In my web.config, for the production site I have custom errors mode set to `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>` so full stack trace should not display - correct? I only need the extra details in debug so security should not be an issue?

Comment: @P-Grote also dont understan what you mean by `Extend your catch block like this catch (Exception ex) and pass the exception.` I'm already doing that in my original post?

Comment: Yes, if your are using a different config for production there are no security issus. Yes you already doing this in your original post, you should only replace the line `return InternalServerError(new Exception(ex.Message));` with this line `return InternalServerError(ex);`